# Can I modify the TFS Task Board instead of my Template?

Tags: tfs

My company just finished upgrading to TFS 2012.  I was very excited to try out the new task board.  But I am getting errors like this one:

> [Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TaskWorkItems/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear as tasks on your sprint backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: TaskWorkItems. **The following states do not exist** in any of the work item types: **Done**.

We renamed our "Done" state to "DevDone", because we also have a done state for testing.

Am I required to move this back to Done for it to work?  Or can I somehow map the state that the task board is looking for to my "DevDone" state?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the CommonConfiguration.xml file associated with your Team Project to use the new state name.  You can do this via the command-line witadmin importcommonprocessconfig: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh500413(v=vs.110).aspx

First do an export, edit the XML file (the format is pretty self-explanatory), then re-import.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a new column for Task, you need to update Task state in the task xml AND modify the state in the process config.

If you need to add other Work item (Test Case in my exemple), you can follow this article (write for TFS 2013 but there is no big difference for 2012)

http://fabienguede.blogspot.fr/2014/03/add-test-case-to-task-board.html

Hope this can help you